# Smallest integer larger than lg N

Tags: java, algorithm, math, bit-manipulation

I was reading somewhere that:

> The smallest integer larger than lg N
>   is the number of bits required to
>   represent N in binary, in the same way
>   that the smallest integer larger than
>   log10 N is the number of digits
>   required to represent N in decimal.
>
> The Java statement
>
> ```
> for (lgN = 0; N > 0; lgN++, N /= 2) ;
> ```
>
> is a simple way to compute the
>   smallest integer larger than lg N

I maybe missing something here but how does the Java statement calculate the smallest integer larger than lg N?

Comment: Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm#Integer

Comment: heh 9 responses so far.  SO _looooves_ loops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have any problem just tracing this on sample input?

```
step 1) N = 10, lgN = 0
step 2) N = 5,  lgN = 1
step 3) N = 2,  lgN = 2
step 4) N = 1,  lgN = 3
step 5) N = 0,  lgN = 4
```

lgN is 4 in the end. That's the smallest integer larger than `log(2, 10)`

Answer (score 8):

it might be clearer if rewritten as a while loop:

```
lgN = 0
while( N > 0 ) {
    lgN++;
    N = N/2;
}
```

Which can be thought of as "how many times do we have to right shift before we have shifted off all the 1s" (leaving us with a zero)

Comment: Which, for clarity, could use `N = N >>> 1` (in my mind anyways, because arithmetic operators don't evoke bit operations in my mind).  This is the "bit-oriented approach" (in other words, your description matches closer to the direct problem of "how many bits does N occupy") whereas the code given in the question is closer to the "arithmetic approach" which is "compute log N" (since it could just as easily compute in a base other than 2).

Comment: It's great that everybody upvotes this, but I don't see how this answer does anything but restate the question in a slightly different form. When the loop finishes, why does the variable `lgN` equal the log base 2 of N?

Comment: It doesn't, it contains 1+floor(log2 N).

Answer (score 3):

Write it out on paper.  Example, for N = 1750

```
   lgN   N      N > 0?
1   0    1750   y
2   1    875    y
3   2    437    y
4   3    218    y
5   4    109    y
6   5    54     y
7   6    27     y
8   7    13     y
9   8    6      y  
10  9    3      y
11  10   1      y
12  11   0      n  stop; lgN = 11
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to the question you should ask, namely how to best compute this:

Don't do this with a loop. Calculate it directly:

```
int bits = (int) Math.floor(Math.log(n)/Math.log(2)) + 1;
```

Be careful not to let `n == 0`.

Comment: About time someone puts an end to this loop madness. Thank you uckelman.

Comment: "Best" in what sense? This may look cleaner, but it's certainly inefficient to use floating-point arithmetic for what can be done with bit-arithmetic.

Comment: @casablance: *Inefficient*?!? Unless you're doing heavy scientific computing (which you propably wouldn't in Java with a handcoded lg), there is no way the logarithm is anything near a bottleneck for your code. When Knuth dies, his corpse will spin fast enough to generate enough power for the next few generations.

Comment: You're not computing the same value. It takes 3 bits to store the value 4, but ceil(lg2(4)) is 2. The expression you want is 1+floor(lg2(4)), which matches for all positive values of int32.

Comment: @casablanca: Even if you have a bored fpu sitting around?

Comment: @delnan, @Douglas: I fully understand that this is in no way a bottleneck but I just thought I'd add a tangential comment since the answer has already digressed from the OP's question. Indeed this maybe the best you can do in *Java*, but on most processors, a single bit-scan instruction will get you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @Strilanc: Yes, you're right. I fixed the code (and also added the missing `int` cast, since `Math.floor` returns a `double`).

Comment: I feel like I should also point out that this is, at a low level, a pretty silly way to compute the number of bits. A double directly contains the information you want, but you have to do this logarithm and floor stuff to get it out.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is calculating log_2 of N. So think in terms of binary, how many bits does it take to represent N? The way you find out is count the number of times you can divide N by 2 (shift the bits in N to the right 1 space). The number of times you do this before N reaches 0 is the value you're calculating.

Answer (score 1):

For those going off on a tangent and trying to "stop the loop madness" by providing a more efficient solution to a question that wasn't asked, I propose this which is simultaneously more efficient and readable:

```
 public int bitsNeeded(int n) {
     return 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n);
 }
```

As the [Javadoc for `Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros()`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros(int)) says:

> Note that this method is closely related to the logarithm base 2. For all positive int values x:
>
> - `floor(log2(x)) = 31 - numberOfLeadingZeros(x)`
> - `ceil(log2(x)) = 32 - numberOfLeadingZeros(x - 1)`

I didn't post this before since it was tangential as I said.  The OP was trying to understand the loop, not find the "best" way of doing something.

Answer (score 0):

Consider N in binary form, without all the zeros at the left.

For example, for 19 it would be 10011.

Each N/=2 is shifting this one bit at the right:

- 10011
- 1001
- 100
- 10
- 1
- 0

When N is equal to 0 then lgN (which is the number of step) is equal to log(N).

Answer (score 0):

lg N is smaller than k:

- if and only if N is smaller than 2^k
- if and only if dividing N by 2, k times, results in 0 (remember that integer division rounds down).

So, the least integer greater than lg N is the number of divisions by 2 required to get to 0, and that's what the loop does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is correct, the code would be using a "lgN" variable that exists outside of the loop.  When the loop finishes, "lgN" would be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes, for base 2 logarithm... (ln N)/(ln 2), not the natural logarithm

Answer (score 0):

It is a for loop.  Its initial condition is that lgN has the value zero.  The loop continues so long as N is greater than zero.  At each iteration in the loop, it adds one to lgN and divides N by 2.

That's a very literal translation of what the loop does.  How does it work?  Well, the first time through the loop, it increments lgN and divides N by 2.  So if N was 1, N is now zero, and we're done.  If N was larger than one, we have to iterate again.  Every time you can divide N by 2 without getting to zero is another required bit in the binary representation.  The code basically asks, "how many times can I divide N by 2 before I reach 0?" and that is the smallest integer larger than lg N.